# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test_proj.settings'

Tags: python, django, deployment, cpanel, wsgi

I am trying to deploy django app on **cPanel 78.0.45**. See [Setup Python App Configuration here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fruz.png). 
*djangoapp* is the application root . The structure of *djangoapp* directory is as follows:

```
__pycache__/
     passenger_wsgi.cpython-37.pyc
log
passenger_wsgi.py
public
tmp
test_proj/                 /*the name of django app*/
     test_proj/
          __init__.py
          __pycache__
          settings.py
          urls.py
          wsgi.py
     manage.py
```

Script of **passenger_wsgi.py** is:

```
import imp
import os
import sys


sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))

wsgi = imp.load_source('wsgi', 'test_proj/test_proj/wsgi.py')
application = wsgi.application
```

Script of **wsgi.py** is:

```
"""
WSGI config for test_proj project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'test_proj.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Script of **manage.py** is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'test_proj.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Now the problem is that when I hit the Application URL it shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXUQz.png). I checked the log to trace the problem, it throws the following exception:

```
App 36033 output: ModuleNotFoundError
App 36033 output: : No module named 'test_proj.settings'
```

Since the **settings.py** exists in the **test_proj** package, I am unable to figure out why this exception is being thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I don't know this is the best way but it solved my issue
- what I did is change the folder structure
- my previous folder structure was like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN5WD.png)
- I changed it like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVc9I.png) by moving all the files in [django] -> [ProjectName]
  -> [ProjectName] to [django] -> [ProjectName]
- but I think there may be a way to solve this by changing the path. But I'm new to django and I post this just after I solved the issue